# Let's Encrypt Certificate for domain mapped to localhost

Tags: node.js, express, https, lets-encrypt

I need to install Let's Encrypt Certificate for https to localhost, for development reason,

I mapped localhost to `dev.{ MyDomain }.com` in file `/etc/hosts`, but when I run

```bash
certbot certonly --manual
```

and I set dev.{ MyDomain }.com

I get this error:

```
Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: manual). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
  Domain: dev.{ MyDomain }.com
  Type:   dns
  Detail: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for dev.{ MyDomain }.com - check that a DNS record exists for this domain; DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up AAAA for dev.{ MyDomain }.com - check that a DNS record exists for this domain

Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to verify the manually created challenge files. Ensure that you created these in the correct location.

Some challenges have failed.
```

off course I have the correct string when I make a http request to `http://dev.{ MyDomain }.com/.well-known/acme-chellenge/<challeng-file>`

Comment: If `dev.{ MyDomain }.com` cannot be resolved externally through a proper DNS request it's not going to work (unless you use the `DNS-01` challenge type, but then you might as well configure an A record for the `dev` subdomain). `/etc/hosts` only works locally.

Comment: So I can't get a certificate for a domain mapped on localhost?

Comment: No, you need a proper DNS setup.

Comment: Let's encrypt only issues certificates for domains you can prove you have admin access to.   The check is not performed by certbot, so any local hosts file modifications are just useless, you need a real DNS address resolvable by a public DNS server.